# Rollback an AWS Amplify deploy?

Tags: aws-amplify, rollback, redeploy

I have pushed a broken change to my prod instance on AWS Amplify and I am attempting to rollback to a previous working deploy. I've reviewed this [guide](https://iotespresso.com/revert-your-app-to-a-previous-version-in-aws-amplify/) to attempt to solve the issue but it looks to be an older version of the AWS Amplify console. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
git reset --hard <stable commit number>
git push --force
```

It will push stable changes in github and will run aws amplify build and also maintain development branch for for broken or updated changes

Comment: aws amplify not git